# Regex pattern for minimum currency

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, docusignapi

I need a regex pattern for minimum currency, in this instance, so a number under $1000.00 cannot be input into the field. only $1000.00 and up to say $9999.00. This is for a DocuSign Template.

Number 1., The one-time transfer amount from the screenshot must be 1000.00 or higher.

Number 2., The monthly selection must be $100.00 or more.

Here is what I currently have to make them input it in Monetary form. I am struggling with adding the currency thresholds/minimums described above.

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$
```

I am a novice at best so thank you for any help in advance.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to build a single regex that validates all these: 1) $1000.00 to $9999.00, 2) -$1000.00 to -$9999.00, and 3) $100 to infinity? (There are different flavors of regex, and there are online regex testers. [Here's one](https://regex101.com/).)

Comment: If you've found my answer below helpful to solving your problem, please consider accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want something along these lines for `100.00` to `9999.99`  you would want a different regex per field.

`^[1-9]\d{2,3}\.\d{2}$`

https://regex101.com/r/K2SnS7/1

Check that out and play with it.  You just need to think in a regex manner, what are the values I can have first, probably not zero. So 1 to 9, with between two and three more numbers.  Followed by a decimal and any two numbers.  Good luck!